# get dynamically changed iframe content

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

After dynamically changing the iframe content, how do I get the updated content?

```
    var target = document.getElementById('page_demo').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
```

Will give me a copy of it, but it does not reflect any updates that I have made to it. It returns the content before any changes were made!

Edit:

To further explain what I am trying to do. I am using grapejs to create html pages. I want tto add shortcode to it, to dynamically generate page links and insert them. In grapejs, the shortcodes are represented by icons. It all works, except the second change overwrites the first change. So I need to figure out how to make both (or all, if I add any others) changes happen!

```
$('#page_demo').contents().find("body").html( css + page_data );
$('#page_demo').contents().find("body").css( page_css );

//there are 2 shortcode items pre inserted in to a grapesjs editor
//<div id="insert_navbar"><span title="Navbar" id="iavph" class="fa fa-navicon text-white"></span></div>
//<div id="insert_sidenav"><span title="Sidebar Navigation" class="fa fa-navicon"></span></div>

// check if we need to insert a navbar at shortcode location!
if( document.getElementById( "page_demo" ).contentWindow.document.getElementById( "insert_navbar" ) ){
    var e = document.getElementById( "page_demo" ).contentWindow.document.getElementById( "insert_navbar" );
    // extract class part!!!
    var parts = e.innerHTML.split('class="');
    var thePart = parts[1];
    var nextparts = thePart.split('"');
    var the_class = nextparts[0];
    //remove place holder icon
    var final_class = the_class.replace('fa fa-navicon', '').trim();

    //generate navbar link items!
    $.post( "quicknav.php", { content_changed : 1, final_class : final_class }, function( data ){ 
        // update display
        e.innerHTML = data;
        //the navbar links have been inserted!
    });
}

// check if we need to insert a sidebar menu at shortcode location!
if( document.getElementById( "page_demo" ).contentWindow.document.getElementById( "insert_sidenav" ) ){
    var e = document.getElementById( "page_demo" ).contentWindow.document.getElementById( "insert_sidenav" );
    // extract class part!!!
    var parts = e.innerHTML.split('class="');
    var thePart = parts[1];
    var nextparts = thePart.split('"');
    var the_class = nextparts[0];
    //remove place holder icon
    var final_class = the_class.replace('fa fa-navicon', '').trim();

    //generate side nav link items!
    $.post( "quicknav.php", { content_changed : 2, final_class : final_class }, function( data2 ){ 
        // update display
        e.innerHTML = data2;
        //*** once we ger here, the final output has changed to reflect that the side nav links are present
        // but the navbar links have reverted back to the initial state before insertion
    });
}
```

Edit 2:
There is some thing very weird going on with my code. As an experiment, I copied the content of the iframe in to a text area. I then stepped through it one line at a time. It showed that the part the changes were both being made, but as soon as I got to a line that got a sub string, the first change was erased, Not sure where to goo from here. Does anyone know why the following line would affect the contents of a text area?

```
 var res = new_content.substring( insert_sidenav + 16, insert_start + 9 );
```

Note that the variable new_content is just a text string!

Comment: But I don't want to add, I want to replace a specified part of the page!

Comment: So far there are two items that I want to replace if they exist. In the future, this may expand to be more than just two items! Also, the reason I want to replace them, is I need to remove the icon in them, because it is just a place holder, in the grapesjs editor. A symbol, that tells the person editing, that the item is there!!

Comment: "get dynamically changed iframe content" is the problem?" If I change a part of the content, I then need to get the entire body of the content, which includes the updated content. Attempts so far have return the contents, with out any changes at all made to it. Which is why I need to "get dynamically changed iframe content"

Comment: There is some thing very weird going on with my code. As an experiment, I copied the content of the iframe in to a text area. I then stepped through it one line at a time. It showed that the part the changes were both being made, but as soon as I got to a line that got a sub string, the first change was erased, Not sure where to goo from here.

Comment: I used the textarea because I wanted to view the actual source code, not rendered html!

Comment: Solved it, apparently, it does not like re declaring variables. So the line in edit2, with 'var' prefix removed, it now all works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`.innerHTML` returns static content in the form of a string that represents the HTML Text Tree.

**Given:** Same origin content, **Then**:

Perhaps you should consider using a Live NodeList or HTMLCollection thus:

```
target = document.getElementById('page_demo').contentWindow
                           .document.getElementsByTagName('body')
```